# Chrome autofill messes up phone number on kentico bizform

Tags: kentico, autofill

I have a website built in Kentico 6.  There is a contact us form with phone number field. Kentico's phone field format is US Phone Number which gives you three boxes (3+3+4). I have an address setup in Chrome's autofill settings with phone number as 123-456-7890 format (I tried (123) 456-7890 and 1234567890 as well).  When filling out the form I select the value from the autofill and all fields are populated correctly except the phone number: phone number's area code and the next 3 numbers are flipped.  For example: the real phone number is 612-556-9003, but after autofill it is displayed as 556-612-9003. [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IVeK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what would cause that, but you could switch it over to a text field and then use a client side libary to control the field content or give it a format.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had good luck using that form control without having to customize it.  So the best thing to do is change the field control from a Phone number to a Textbox and add a regex to it to validate a phone number.  [Here is a good example](http://www.regextester.com/17) of a valid 10 digit phone number regex.

Comment: I tried this - I created another Phone number field as textbox, but when selecting autofill, it fills the textbox with phone number WITHOUT area code.

Comment: Then you need to make sure your autofill is correct.  You can review this in the Chrome settings.

Comment: Checked that - autofill has the correct phone number.